# Calculate limit with modulus

Tags: limits

Calculate $$\lim_{x \to x^-_o} \frac{x^2+x-2}{|x+2|}$$when $x_o = -2$

how can I work with the absolute value in this situation?

$$\lim_{x \to -2^-} \frac{(x+2)(x-1)}{|x+2|}$$

answer of limit= $-\frac{3}{2}$ (it was wrong in the book)

Comment: The answer you gave in the end is 100% false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$x\to -2^-$ means that $x $ come closer to $-2$ by the left side,  or

$x $ stays less than $-2$

thus $x <-2 \iff x+2 <0$

in this case $$|x+2|=-(x+2)$$

After simplification by the common factor $(x+2)$, the function becomes

$$\frac {x-1}{-1}=1-x $$

the limit is $$1-(-2)=3$$

Comment: I had arrived at $3$, but the book results in -$\frac{3}{2}$. Probably the book is wrong?

Comment: @MuradinBronzebeard The only book with no error is Coran.

Answer (score 2):

Recall that
$$|x+2| =
\begin{cases}
-(x+2),  & \text{if } x<2 \\
x+2, & \text{if } x\ge2
\end{cases}$$
Since it has a $-2^-$, you know which case you have to do.

You should also NOT be getting the answer which you provided. $-\dfrac 32$ is incorrect.

Comment: Then that's it. I was in a looping

Answer (score 2):

Note that since $x+2<0$

$$\lim_{x \to -2^-} \frac{(x+2)(x-1)}{|x+2|}=\lim_{x \to -2^-} \frac{(x+2)(x-1)}{-(x+2)}=\lim_{x \to -2^-} -x+1=3$$

Comment: I had arrived at $3$, but the book results in -$\frac{3}{2}$. Probably the book is wrong?

Comment: Gimusi, I did not downvote, but check the absolute value. Your answer should be $3$.

Comment: @idk Yes of course! Thanks I fix

Comment: @Salahamam_Fatima Yes I' fixed now! Never underestimate the absolute value! I've made only a quick check and I was uncorrect! Thanks